# How does the locking mechanism of a secure bicycle dock work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to understand the physical locking mechanism used in bicycle docks, as in the image below, to secure the bike to the dock.

[image]

I want an in-depth understanding of the mechanism for a design project I am doing on bike sharing systems. I most interested in the type of docks [Citi Bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citi_Bike) uses.

Comment: Have you visited a station, unlocked a bike, and looked inside?

Answer (score 1):

[This nymag page](http://nymag.com/guides/summer/2012/communal-bikes/) says "The mechanical titanium lock sends pins into the docked bike".

[This citibikeblog page](http://citibikeblog.tumblr.com/post/91458138556/dock-dynamics) shows a view inside the dock and states that when the lock hasn't worked properly, then without a bike in there may still be a "metal bar across the slot" - this is presumably the titanium lock pin (not that I can see it in that page's photo).

[This google image search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=825&bih=839&q=front+of+a+citibike&oq=front+of+a+citibike&gs_l=img.3...310.3798.0.4053.19.13.0.6.0.0.172.1444.7j6.13.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.12.1356...0.ZjpB6HqI6nc#tbm=isch&q=citibike+front+triangle&imgrc=90PAzxws2cjzaM%3A) shows the goldish triangle at the front of the bike which goes into the dock for locking. You can see a hole at the front of it, and some dimples part way down - presumably the pins are supposed to engage one or either of these.

I'm afraid I don't know how the pin is sent across.

Comment: Yes, i want to know how that triangles attaches to the dock. What mechanism is used and also the drawbacks of that mechanism.

Comment: @bikeankit Andy has already explained this to you. The bracket (or "triangle" piece) has a hole in it, and a pin inside the dock moves into that hole to lock the bike in place. Surely you can think up some pros and cons yourself, for the school project that you, and not we, are responsible for completing.